# What are the layouts used in Android Market application on Android phones?

Tags: android, android-layout, google-play

What are the Layouts used in Android Market Application on Android phones?

Included screenshots below, what kind of layouts this is making use of ?

[image: Android market application screenshot]

Comment: it s all are in linear layout and use dynamic listview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Market uses ListView mostly. The carousel of images at the top is a custom view. More info here: http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2010/12/13/meet-the-green-goblin-part-1.html